# Intermediate Rings that are not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ are two rings such that $R_1$ $\subseteq$ $R_2$ and $R_2$ is a finitely generated ring over $R_1$. We know that, if $R_1$ is Noetherian and $S$ is a ring such that $R_1$ $\subseteq$ $S$ $\subseteq$ $R_2$ and $R_2$ is a finitely generated module over $S$, then $S$ is a finitely generated ring over $R_1$.

I found out in the June edition of The American Mathematical monthly that if we remove the condition that "$R_2$ is a finitely generated module over $S$", then there exists examples where $S$ might not be a finitely generated ring over $R_1$ and they construct an example using heavy machineries, I was thinking whether a '*simpler*' example could be constructed.

And Also if one could provide a *general algorithm* on constructing such rings, it will be very much appreciable.

Comment: I have no idea what it would mean to give a "general algorithm" here.

Comment: @EricWofsey it means that my question has 2 parts, first part asks to give just an example of the fact and the second one asks to give a $general$ mechanism to construct such examples.

Comment: The first paragraph refers to the [Artin-Tate lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tate_lemma)

Comment: I am sure examples of this have been given in this site a few times — I myself have written a couple of answers, in fact! Have you looked before asking?

Comment: Tip: wrapping a text with asterisks produces *italics*. Using double asterisks gives **bold**. The spacing in such italics is better than what you get with $math$ $italics$, where letters are treated as symbols (as they should). If you prefer the latter, then I apologize. We can roll my edit back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R_1 = k, R_2 = k[x,y], S = k[x,xy,xy^2,xy^3,\dots]$.